# plt.violinplot: Adjusting the length of the horizontal min and max lines

Tags: python, matplotlib, violin-plot

I created a violinplot with matplotlib. Now, I would like to reduce the horizontal length of the two lines for the minimal and maximum values. How can I do that?

Here is my code. The code is reduced to the necessary information for a better overview.

```
# Initialize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import statistics


# Creation of violinplots
Core_values = np.loadtxt("pathtofile/xyz.txt", comments=None, delimiter=None, converters=None, skiprows=0, usecols=0,
                  unpack=False, ndmin=0, encoding=None, max_rows=None, like=None)

Core = plt.violinplot(Core_values, positions=[0], points=500)


# Look of the violinplot
for vp in Core["bodies"]:
    vp.set_facecolor("cornflowerblue")
    vp.set_zorder(2)
    vp.set_alpha(1)
    vp.set_linewidth(1)

for vp_part in ("cbars", "cmins", "cmaxes"):
    vp = Core[vp_part]
    vp.set_edgecolor("black")

plt.show()
```

The screenshot below shows what I mean: the top and bottom black line of the violinplot. I would like to decrease their horizontal length.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matplotlib's [tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/statistics/customized_violin.html#sphx-glr-gallery-statistics-customized-violin-py) suggests calculating and drawing the lines in a separate step.

Here is an alternative approach, looping through the generated lines and reducing their lengths (to 40% in the example code):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(123)
core_values = [np.random.normal(.1, 3, 10000).cumsum(), np.random.normal(.1, 2, 10000).cumsum()]

core = plt.violinplot(core_values, positions=[0, 1])

for vp in core["bodies"]:
    vp.set_facecolor("cornflowerblue")
    vp.set_zorder(2)
    vp.set_alpha(1)
    vp.set_linewidth(1)

factor_x, factor_y = 0.4, 1 # factor to reduce the lengths
for vp_part in ("cbars", "cmaxes", "cmins"):
    vp = core[vp_part]
    if vp_part in ("cmaxes", "cmins"):
        lines = vp.get_segments()
        new_lines = []
        for line in lines:
            center = line.mean(axis=0)
            line = (line - center) * np.array([factor_x, factor_y]) + center
            new_lines.append(line)
        vp.set_segments(new_lines)
    vp.set_edgecolor("black")

plt.show()
```

[image: plt.violinplot with adjusted extremes]